# How to send variables to an element in CakePHP 3.x from a controller and keep variables when using element in a different view?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.1, cakephp-3.x

I created an application that allows admins to save slider content to the database and now I want to include the slider on the home page. I have a Slides controller with a slider function that just send the slides content to the slider view.

Here is that controller function:

```
public function slider()
{
    $slides = $this->Slides->find('all');
    $this->set('slides', $slides);
    $this->set('_serialize', ['slides']);
}
```

The view for that function only has the following in it:

```
<?= $this->element('slider'); ?>
```

I then created an element file called slider and process the slides there. When I go to url /slides/slider the slider is working, but when I go to the root or home page, the slider is empty. It doesn't seem to be keeping the $slides variable in the element.

On the home page:

```
<?= $this->element('slider'); ?> // then the rest of the home page follows this.
```

So how do I keep the variable or make it so that I can have the slider view on the home page as well?

Comment: Did you tried it in appcontroller ?

Comment: On the home page, how are you initializing the `$slides` variable? Or are you hoping that the element will somehow remember that data from a previous page load?

Comment: I am not sending the variable in the homepage, I am not sure how I would do that. The home page is a static view controlled by the pages controller, so I am unsure how to send the slides variable to that page or somehow keep the data in the element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best practice in your case is to use [Cells](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/cells.html):

> View cells are small mini-controllers that can invoke view logic and
>   render out templates. They provide a light-weight modular replacement
>   to requestAction().

1. From the base App dir run `cd bin` from the console
2. then run `cake bake cell Slider` from the console
3. Go to `src/View/Cell/SliderCell.php`.
4. edit the display function,

as the following

```
public function display()
{
    $this->loadModel('Slides');
    $slides= $this->Slides->find('all');
    $this->set('slides', $slides);
}
```

5. Now go to the `src/Template/Cell/Slides/display.ctp`, and play with `$slides` in the tepmlate.
6. To render the Cell anywhere just use this: `<?= $this->cell('Slider') ?>`

Comment: Great answer. Thank You! Just to clarify something, I am using windows, and according to docs I had to use the command bin\cake bake cell Slider if anyone has a problem running the command Ayman Alkom gave.

Comment: Also, if I didn't already have the model(entity and table) I would need to create them first correct?

Comment: Yes, you can also cd to the bin dir and call 'cake' simply, the cake 3 will automatically find the app base url

Answer (score 2):

The variables are not sent from the Controller to an element, but from a view.

What you can do is set variables in your controller like this :

```
$this->set('myvariable','any value');
```

And, according to cakephp 3 documentation, in the view you can pass the parameter like this:

```
echo $this->element('helpbox', [
    "varToElement" => $myvariable
]);
```

Source : https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#passing-variables-into-an-element